# SimpleSAMLphp Cannot retrieve metadata for IdP 'http://simpleidp/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php' because it isn't a valid IdP for this SP

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I'm stuck with error simplesamlPHP
    SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
    Backtrace:
    0 /var/www/simplesp/www/module.php:180 (N/A)
    Caused by: SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Cannot retrieve metadata for IdP 'http://URLIDP/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php' because it isn't a valid IdP for this SP.
    Backtrace:
    2 /var/www/simplesp/modules/saml/lib/Auth/Source/SP.php:112 (sspmod_saml_Auth_Source_SP::getIdPMetadata)
    1 /var/www/simplesp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:91 (require)
    0 /var/www/simplesp/www/module.php:137 (N/A)

Config for me with SP :

```
/var/www/simplesp/metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php

$metadata['URLIDP'] = array(
    'SingleSignOnService'  => 'URLIDP/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
    'SingleLogoutService'  => 'URLIDP/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
    'certFingerprint'      => 'c9ed4dfb07caf13fc21e0fec1572047eb8a7a4cb'
);
```

Config for me with Idp :
/var/www/simpleidp/metadata/saml20-sp-remote.php

```
$metadata['URLSP/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp'] = array(
    'SingleLogoutService' =>
        array(
            0 =>
                array(
                    'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
                    'Location' => 'URLSP/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp',
                ),
        ),
    'AssertionConsumerService' =>
        array(
            0 =>
                array(
                    'index' => 0,
                    'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
                    'Location' => 'URLSP/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
                ),
            1 =>
                array(
                    'index' => 1,
                    'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post',
                    'Location' => 'URLSP/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/default-sp',
                ),
            2 =>
                array(
                    'index' => 2,
                    'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact',
                    'Location' => 'URLSP/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
                ),
            3 =>
                array(
                    'index' => 3,
                    'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01',
                    'Location' => 'URLSP/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/default-sp/artifact',
                ),
        ),

);
```

Can help me resolve problem ?

Answer (score 2):

On the SP you have it configured to think the IdP's EntityID is `URLIDP`. The error message shows that the IdP thinks its EntityID is `http://URLIDP/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php`. Those two should match. You can update `saml20-idp-remote.php` on the SP with the correct value (e.g update the key in the `$metadata` array).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its not parsing your metadata file. Make sure your saml20-sp-remote.php file starts with the line

`<?php`

So it knows its PHP. If you've created a new file from the output of the metadata parser, it doesn't add this for you. The fragment it gives you is expected to be pasted into an existing php file.

It worked for me.